# sort column based on alphabets (A00, B00, AA0, AB0, BA0 etc.)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with alphabet values. I would like to sort it based on alphabets as detailed below.
Input I have:

```
A00
B00
AA0
BA0
AB0
C00
Z00
```

Output I need:

```
A00
B00
C00
Z00
AA0
AB0
BA0
```

The problem is that with sort_values, I get below output as the values are sorted based on first alphabet and AA0 and AB0 are coming after A00 and BA0 after B00. I would like to have these after Z00:

```
A00
AA0
AB0
B00
BA0
C00
Z00
```

Comment: All string have the same length?

Comment: @Corralien yes, they all have same length

Answer (score 6):

You can [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the letters and pad them with a 0 on the left with [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) (or [`rjust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rjust.html)), then use this as `key` to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = df.sort_values(by='col', key=lambda s: s.str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False).str.zfill(10))
```

Output:

```
   col
0  A00
1  B00
5  C00
6  Z00
2  AA0
4  AB0
3  BA0
```

Intermediate:

```
df['col'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False).str.zfill(10)

0    000000000A
1    000000000B
2    00000000AA
3    00000000BA
4    00000000AB
5    000000000C
6    000000000Z
Name: col, dtype: object
```

With `rjust`:

```
df['col'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False).str.rjust(10)

0             A
1             B
2            AA
3            BA
4            AB
5             C
6             Z
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: I tested it with 'AAAA0' it works too. It seems to be the answer.

Comment: This works wonders :).

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.join(df['col'].str.split(r'(?<=\D)(?=\d)', regex=True, expand=True))
 .assign(aux=lambda x: x[1]+x[0])
 .sort_values('aux')['col'].to_frame())
```

Output:

```
   col
0  A00
1  B00
5  C00
6  Z00
2  AA0
4  AB0
3  BA0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

First we sort by the column, then we do a second sort on the length of letters found in the string

```
(df.sort_values('col')
.sort_values('col',key = lambda x: x.str.findall(r'[A-Za-z]').str.len()))
```

Output:

```
   col
0  A00
1  B00
5  C00
6  Z00
2  AA0
4  AB0
3  BA0
```